# Of me / of mine / by me

Tags: word-choice

I'm wondering how you would say that because it sounds really weird to me:

Would you say "stuff by me/of me/of mine"?

For example if you posted things on Instagram and would say something like "official stuff by/of me" cause I saw someone who used "official stuff of me" as his description on Instagram and that sounds so wrong to me still. So what would you say?

Answer (score 2):

You would say "my stuff." It does sound wrong to say "official stuff of me"; it's probably intended to be humorous. In normal usage, you would say "my official stuff."

Comment: Thank you very much! I also supposed that it's meant be wrong so that really helps me!

Answer (score 1):

> **stuff by me**
>
> The photo exhibit is full of *stuff by me*.

means *stuff* you produced,as opposed to *stuff* lying along side you.

> **stuff of me**
>
> Q: Do you have any things from when you were a baby?
>   A: Here's a box with pictures and baby boots and my rattle.
>        *here's some stuff of me when I was a baby*

means *stuff* about me, along the lines of "a photograph of me", "an article of me", *stuff* is used as a general catch all.

> **stuff of mine**
>
> The car is full of *stuff of mine*.
>   The car is full of *my stuff*.

means *stuff* which belongs to you.